# How can one Sort String alphabetically and remove duplicate characters from string using Scala

Tags: java, scala

For example, let's say:
I have a String:

val x = "WUBRBUG"

How Can I make String as:

val x = "BGRUW"

Comment: what you are trying to sort are the characters in the String, not the String itself. what have you tried, and what's not working? this is quite easy if you put yourself to it for a few minutes

Comment: "How can one Sort String alphabetically and remove duplicate characters" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x.distinct.sorted // will give the result as sorted and without duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

String is an array of characters. So basically you can apply list operations on it.

```
val x = "WUBRBUG"
x.distinct.sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the String to Array and just get the distinct values in array.

```
scala>  val x = "WUBRBUG"
x: String = WUBRBUG

scala> x.toCharArray.distinct.sorted
res18: Array[Char] = Array(B, G, R, U, W)

scala> x.toCharArray.distinct.sorted.mkString
res19: String = BGRUW
```

Comment: That seems like an unnecessary extra step.